# How to convert ActiveX to Jquery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a project I'm working on to where I need to convert some .js files written for ActiveX. I'm not very familiar with ActiveX, so please spare me.

In the file is has written

```
this.m_DOM = new XMLHttpRequest();
this.m_DOM = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
this.m_DOM.async = false;
```

Can someone please help me convert this to a JQuery/AJAX function?

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery's [AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? It's easy to understand.

Comment: I've been looking over it, but I can't seem to find exactly what I need.

Comment: using `async = false` defeats the purpose (*and initials*) of **AJAX** (*Asynchronous Javascript and XML*)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is just what you need.  Just add the options you need to the object, and that's it.  Here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    type: 'GET', // or POST
    data: {id: 3}, // any data you want to send to the server (optional)
    async: false, // note: this will lock up your browser
                  // only use it if you *really* need to
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```